# I am getting an error while opening a .pickle file in itellij

Tags: pickle, file-not-found

[The file is in the same directory. The path is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAv1R.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "../Deep-Learning/" and use only "cnn_min_max.pickle" as path

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Still the same problem

Comment: Ah okay. Maybe the problem could be the "-" in the "Deep-Learning" path. If is not this try to use the absolute path but i think is not the best solution.